# Is there an equivalent to oracle SEGMENT CREATION in cockroachdb

Tags: oracle, database-schema, cockroachdb

I'm adjusting my oracle table definition for cockroachdb, is there any equivalent to oracle `SEGMENT CREATION` in cockroachdb?

I also asked this question on [cockroachDB forum](https://forum.cockroachlabs.com/t/equivalent-to-oracle-segment-creation-in-cockroachdb/848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB does not have anything exactly equivalent to Oracle's "segments". It has "ranges", which serve some of the same purposes but do not represent a pre-allocation of space. There are no options at table creation time that control the creation of ranges. (You can change `range_max_bytes` in a [zone config](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/configure-replication-zones.html), although that's not the same as the Oracle option that I think you're referring to). See the [FAQ](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-does-cockroachdb-scale) for more on ranges.